# In hibernate, how can JSP value match the variable in Entity class

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have a jsp page, some codes are below

```
<c:forEach var="tempCustomer" items="${customers}">
    <c:url var="updateLink" value="/customer/showFormForUpdate">
        <c:param name="customerId" value="${tempCustomer.id}"/>
    </c:url>
    <c:url var="deleteLink" value="/customer/delete">
        <c:param name="customerId" value="${tempCustomer.id}"/>
    </c:url>
    <tr>
        <!-- .firstName must match the variable in () customer setFirstName(String firstName) -->
        <td> ${tempCustomer.firstName} </td>
        <td> ${tempCustomer.lastName} </td>
        <td> ${tempCustomer.email} </td>
        <td>
            <a href="${updateLink}">Update</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="${deleteLink}" onclick="if(!(confirm('U sure u want to delete'))) return false">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

And below is my entity class

```
package com.learning.spring.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity
    @Table(name="customer")
    public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int Id;
    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    public Customer() {

    }

    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(int Id) {
        this.Id = Id;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

As you can see,in JSP page, `value="${tempCustomer.id}"`, I use `id`, which is lowercase `i`. However, in the entity class, I define it as below, which use `Id`, uppercase `I`.

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int Id;
```

So how can Hibernate map `id` to `Id`? And if I use `Id` instead in JSP page, the program throws Id not found exception.

In addition, I thought about case sensitive, but I found if I change `${tempCustomer.firstName}` to `${tempCustomer.firstname}`. it throws the firstname not found exception.

And help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSP EL uses java beans naming convention to convert names of properties to corresponding getters because it cannot access private fields directly. And according to Javabeans spec for both `id` and `Id` properties standard getter name is `getId()` that is why it works for both options. But for `firstName` getter is `getFirstName()` and for `firstname` getter is `getFirstname()`. Since you class has only `getFirstName()` that's why only `firstName` works in EL.

UPDATE

So I've checked the code. To get list of available properties that could be used in EL Java checks **methods** of the class. For getters like `getSomeStuff()` if removes first 3 letters (`get`) and then replaces first letter with lower case. So `getSomeStuff()` is converted to `someStuff`. And this is a name which could be used in JSP EL. Because of this validation `id` is a valid property and `Id` is not though proeprty `Id` is what actually exists in object. But JSP uses getters to get actual values. It doesn't check if actual properties exist and what are their names.

Pieces of code form `java.beans.Introspector`

```
if (argCount == 0) {
  if (name.startsWith(GET_PREFIX)) {
    // Simple getter
    pd = new PropertyDescriptor(this.beanClass, name.substring(3), method, null);
 } else if (resultType == boolean.class && name.startsWith(IS_PREFIX)) {
   // Boolean getter
   pd = new PropertyDescriptor(this.beanClass, name.substring(2), method, null);
 }
}

public static String decapitalize(String name) {
    if (name == null || name.length() == 0) {
        return name;
    }
    if (name.length() > 1 && Character.isUpperCase(name.charAt(1)) &&
                    Character.isUpperCase(name.charAt(0))){
        return name;
    }
    char chars[] = name.toCharArray();
    chars[0] = Character.toLowerCase(chars[0]);
    return new String(chars);
}
```

And code for `java.beans.ProeprtyDescriptor`

```
PropertyDescriptor(Class<?> bean, String base, Method read, Method write) throws IntrospectionException {
    if (bean == null) {
        throw new IntrospectionException("Target Bean class is null");
    }
    setClass0(bean);
    setName(Introspector.decapitalize(base));
    setReadMethod(read);
    setWriteMethod(write);
    this.baseName = base;
}
```

Comment: thx for your help. I understand firstname part. But what I do not understand is why value="${tempCustomer.Id}" does not work? as you mentioned both id and Id are standard getter name is getId().